# Android high score not zero with first ever app launch

Tags: android, reset

I got my high score setup correctly, as in you play the game, if the score is higher than previous score then use SharedPreferences and Editor (editor putint ,editor commit when commit data then pref.getint to get data).  It works as I expect and overwrites high score.  I then go back to main menu and click on start button and high score is still correct.  My issue is when you first start the app the high score is not zero. Even with app killer it is not zero, it is the previous high score.  The problem is that if I have someone else install the app they won't start with highscore of 0, but whatever mine is.  I do not know how I can store first ever app launch and then have that value be different so it isnt first launch.  I have a ttext view for highscore in my oncreate and the oncreate has the pref.getint to get the highscores.

Comment: before deploying the app delete the preference

Comment: SharedPreferences are specific to the device. Yours will not be compiled into your exported apk. Rather, they will be created anew on each device that installs and runs your app.

Comment: How can I delete the preference only once and that only once happens at first ever launch?

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out.  Just one question.  When you call pref.clear() then pref.commit() will I be able to do..editor.getint("record secs", secs), I mean does "record secs" get completely deleted so it is not recognized or will it just return 0?